# Find all the maximum directed connected groups from a list of pairs

Tags: python, algorithm, graph, networkx

I would like to find out the maximum directed connected groups from the following pairs.

```
pairs = [
    ('creepy', 'sports'), 
    ('AskReddit', 'creepy'),
    ('AskReddit', 'boardgames'), 
    ('AskReddit', 'television'), 
    ('AskReddit', 'movies'), 
    ('AskReddit', 'history'), 
    ('sports', 'television'), 
    ('creepy', 'movies'), 
    ('history', 'television'), 
    ('movies', 'sports'), 
    ('creepy', 'television'), 
    ('movies', 'television')
]
```

The output that I need to have is:

- Group 1: `('creepy', 'sports', 'television', 'movies')`
- Group 2: `('creepy', 'AskReddit', 'movies', 'television')`
- Group 3: `('AskReddit', 'boardgames')`
- Group 4: `('AskReddit', 'history', 'television')`

For example, I do not want to have the group `('AskReddit', 'history', 'television', 'boardgames')` because there is not a directed connection from `'boardgames'` both to `'television'` and `'history'`.

I made many many tries using directed graphs. I think that this is that I want to find has a specific name in graph theory but I really can not remember it. My first try was with DFS and how can I create a chain of them but the output contains the group that I refer above and I do not want to have it.

I use Python.

All your comments are welcome! Thanks in advance.

Comment: what you seem to want is to find for each node the maximum clique which contains it. A simple approach would be (if you don't have too many nodes) to build all the k-clique then all the (k+1)-clique...
For some given node you would check if some nth-clique contain it otherwise n-1... and so forth

Comment: You are right. I just tried it in Python and now I have the correct groups. I had two days trying to find the solution. I really appreciate your help. I have to study the theory of cliques again. Thank you so so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want to find the maximal [cliques](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clique_problem) containing each node in the graph, where *a maximal clique for v is a largest complete subgraph containing v*.

In [NetworkX](https://networkx.github.io/) we have [`nx.find_cliques`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.clique.find_cliques.html#networkx.algorithms.clique.find_cliques), which does exactly that:

```
G=nx.Graph()
G.add_edges_from(pairs)
max_cliques = list(nx.find_cliques(G))
```

---

```
print(max_cliques)
[['boardgames', 'AskReddit'],
 ['television', 'sports', 'creepy', 'movies'],
 ['television', 'AskReddit', 'history'],
 ['television', 'AskReddit', 'creepy', 'movies']]
```