# How to find cliques without repeating nodes, in a way that puts the largest number of nodes in a clique

Tags: python, algorithm, graph

For example, I have:

```
Item 1
  2,3,4,5,6

Item 2
  1,3

Item 3
  1,2,7

Item 4
  1,5,6

Item 5
  1,4,6,9,12


Item 6
  1,4,5,3

Item 7
  3
```

The desired output would be [1,4,5,6], and either [2,3] or [3,7]

edit:

currently getting all cliques using networkx but need the cliques to be unique, preferably in the way that puts as many nodes as possible into a clique:

```
G=nx.Graph()
G.add_edges_from(pairs)
max_cliques = list(nx.find_cliques(G))
```

need to run through mthe output and make sure it makes sense

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62072069/find-all-the-maximum-directed-connected-groups-from-a-list-of-pairs this might be closer in the direction im looking for

Comment: This is the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clique_problem which is NP hard.

Comment: You could use the cliques from `nx.find_cliques` to formulate a set packing problem as an integer program, then apply an off-the-shelf integer program solver.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat knowing this is a  'set packing problem' is a great way for me to move forward if my recursive algorithm to try each combination and keep track of the best results doesnt work out. thanks!